# uwp mostrecentlyusedlist addition causes COM type exception

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, comexception, storagefile

**StackTrace**

"   at Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList.Add(IStorageItem file, String metadata, RecentStorageItemVisibility visibility)\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.Helpers.FileHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Helpers.DispatcherHelper.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()"

> I am trying to add a StorageFile to **MostRecentlyUsedList** and as a result I am getting this exception.

**Exception**

> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

**Code**

```
internal async static Task AddToHistory(StorageFile fileToBeAdded) => await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(() => StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(fileToBeAdded, "", RecentStorageItemVisibility.AppAndSystem));
```

> I have this static method to use within a static class so I can call it from any page in the app. I can verify that StorageFile object is not null and perfect I also tried to solve it by using **DispatcherHelper** as you can see in the code, but with or without it, exception occurs in both cases.

**Update**

I have tried to add to **FutureAccessList** as well instead of **MostRecentlyUsedList** and I am getting same error in both cases

**Update 2**

accessing the list normally doesn't cause any error, like I can access it with following code

```
var mlist = StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList;
var entries = mlist.Entries;
```

error only occurs when I try to add a storagefile to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in partial StorageFiles I was actually querying the files from KnownFolders.VideoLibrary as per following blog post.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamdwilson/2017/12/20/fast-file-enumeration-with-partially-initialized-storagefiles/

so when we use following indexing option it actually initializes partial storage files for us which causes exception when we try to add it to most recently used list or futureacceslist

```
IndexerOption = IndexerOption.OnlyUseIndexerAndOptimizeForIndexedProperties
```

> So to solve this I am now using **IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable** now I don't get any exception, but ofcourse I am sacrificing the speed I was getting before with partial storage files. Which is disappointing as when trying to do a job with full storagefile, it should automatically initialize the partial storagefile to full storagefile as per the blog post. but that is not the case here unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Touseef. You are correct - there is a bug in how Windows handles the partial StorageFiles internally. Another workaround for now is to use: StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileToBeAdded.Path) to create a new StorageFile object for the file you are adding to the MRU or FAL. You'll still have the fast enumeration but there will be a slow down on adding files to the MRU